# Sorting a list of dates by chronological order?

Tags: c, sorting

My program takes a list of dates in the format of (month day year). It then sorts it in chronological order of most recent events.It should sort the years from 90 to 99, and then from 00 to 12. For example it should sort this list.

> January 1 01
>
> January 1 00
>
> February 28 99
>
> July 17 12
>
> September 10 12
>
> July 1 00
>
> June 30 90
>
> August 25 06
>
> May 27 08
>
> October 1 03

Into this.

> September 10 12
>
> July 17 12
>
> May 27 08
>
> August 25 06
>
> October 1 03
>
> January 1 01
>
> July 1 00
>
> January 1 00
>
> February 28 99
>
> June 30 90

However I can't seem to get the sort to work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* constants for max chars, max day, max year, max size */
enum { MAXC = 12, MAX_DAY = 31, MAX_YEAR = 2017, MAX_SIZE = 1000 };

typedef struct {
    char month[MAXC];   /* either make static or allocate separately */
    unsigned day;
    unsigned year;
} date;

/* empty character remaining in stdin */
void empty_stdin ()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}

/* sort struct date on year */
int sort (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    date *date1 = (date *) a;
    date *date2 = (date *) b;

    if (date2->year != date1->year)
        return (date1->year < date2->year) - (date1->year > date2->year);

    return (date1->year < date2->year) - (date1->year > date2->year);




    return 0;
}

/* output n elements of array of struct date */
void output (date *ar, int n)
{
    int i;

    printf ("\nOutput sorted by year:\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf ("  %s %d %d\n", ar[i].month, ar[i].day, ar[i].year);
}

int main (void) {

    int i, n;
    date *ar = NULL;

    while (1) {     /* obtain valid 'n', compare with using fgets below */

        int rtn; /* varaible to save return of scanf -- always validate */

        //printf ("Enter number of dates to be entered (between 1 & 1000): ");
        if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &n)) != 1) {   /* if conversion failed */
            if (rtn == EOF) {   /* test for user cancelation of input */
                fprintf (stderr, "note: user canceled input, exiting.\n");
                return 0;
            }                   /* otherwise simply an invalid input */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            goto tryagain;
        }

        if (n < 0) {            /* invalid input < 0 */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (n < 0).\n");
            goto tryagain;
        }

        if (n > MAX_SIZE) {     /* invalid input > MAX_SIZE */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input (n > %d).\n", MAX_SIZE);
            goto tryagain;
        }

        break;      /* if we are here - we have a good value, break */

      tryagain:;    /* label for goto to jump over break */

        empty_stdin ();   /* empty characters that remain in input buffer */
    }

    empty_stdin ();     /* empty characters that remain in input buffer */

    /* allocate array of struct ar, n elements */
    if ((ar = malloc (sizeof *ar * n)) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* provide format instructions */
    //printf ("Enter the date month day year\n"
           // "  format, e.g.:  Jan 18 2017\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n;) {   /* loop until all elements filled */

        char buf[MAX_DAY + 1] = "", ans[MAXC] = "";

        //printf (" date[%2d] : ", i + 1);    /* prompt for input */

        /* if fgets return is NULL, EOF encountered */
        if (fgets (buf, MAX_DAY + 1, stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf (stderr, "note: user canceled input, exiting.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        if (*buf == '\n') { /* if first char is '\n', user just hit enter */
            printf ("no input provided, quit (y/n)? ");
            if (fgets (ans, MAXC, stdin) && (*ans == 'y' || *ans == 'Y'))
                return 0;
            else if (!*ans) {   /* if ans NULL, EOF encountered */
                fprintf (stderr, "note: user canceled input, exiting.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        /* parse with sscanf, validate 3 conversion took place */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%11s %u %u", ar[i].month, &ar[i].day, &ar[i].year) != 3)
        {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
            continue;
        }

        i++;    /* only increment if valid sscanf conversion took place */
    }

    qsort (ar, n, sizeof (date), sort);     /* sort by year */

    output (ar, n);     /* output results */

    free (ar);      /* free ar - you allocate it, you free it */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 4 > 3 obviously (as in 04 > 03), but 99 > 4 also, right? If you want things to sort differently than normal, you need to specify the sort criteria you want to control.

Comment: Well I want it to be sorted in this criteria in most recent date with this criteria, compare years from 00 to 12 and sort them in chronological order  and then compare years 90 to 99 and sort. I don't know how to sort becuase I can't just sort it by largest integer. I have already attempted to sort the if it's in the same year

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably to fix the year after you read it in (and then turn it back into the Y2K-prone code when you are printing it out, if necessary).

```
unsigned yy;
... sscanf (buf, "%11s %u %u", ar[i].month, &ar[i].day, &yy) ...
ar[i].year = yy >= 90 ? 1900 + yy : 2000 + yy
```

You'll have to adjust `90` for the actual cutoff you intend to use.

You could similarly translate the month to an integer. Or you could even translate the input to something like a Julian day, thereby making the sort trivial but the output slightly more complicated. Simplifying the sort is a win if you have a lot of dates to sort.

Comment: I'm having a trouble implementing your idea into my code, can you elaborate more?